# Installing aspell in Windows Vista

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

I am trying to install the Win32 port of [aspell](http://aspell.net/win32/) with the English dictionary from [Kevin's website](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/). After working for several hours, installing some unix tool packages for make and tar. I got stuck because all the implementations of tar for windows did not include the command `--strip-components`, which was used in the make file for the word list.

I do not know how to proceed from here. Can anyone tell me or direct me to instructions for installing aspell with any English dictionary? I want to use aspell with Emacs.